# How to getValues from grid and POST them. EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I'm interested by getValues from my grid and post them, using button `confirm` on my grid's custom edit form.

But I haven't idea about how I can `getValues()`. I can't use this or it cause values are accomplished inside 'fieldset' xtype.

How I can get to grid values...maybe exist some method, which to allow to set `grideditable` plugin config to Ajax request config params?

part of my code:

```
Ext.define('Foresto.model.EditListRenters', {
            extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
            xtype: 'rentlist',
            requires: [
                'Ext.grid.plugin.Editable',
                'Foresto.model.RentsListModel'
            ],
            store: {
                model: 'Foresto.model.RentsListModel',
                autoLoad: true,
                pageSize: 0,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: '/myownurl',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        rootProperty: 'results'
                    }

                }
            },
            plugins: [{
                type: 'grideditable',
                triggerEvent: 'doubletap',
                enableDeleteButton: true,
                formConfig: null,

                defaultFormConfig: {
                    xtype: 'formpanel',
                    title: 'Редактировать договор',
                    scrollable: true,
                    items: {
                        xtype: 'fieldset'
                    }
                },

                toolbarConfig: {
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    cls: 'hdr2',
                    height: 46.63,
                    docked: 'top',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        ui: 'decline',
                        cls: 'grbuttons',
                        text: 'cancel',
                        align: 'left',
                        action: 'cancel'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        ui: 'confirm',
                        cls: 'grbuttons',
                        text: 'submit',
                        align: 'right',
                        action: 'submit',
                        handler: function() {

                            var rentset = _.getValues() //how get values??



                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: '/myownurl/contract/',
                                method: 'POST',
                                params: rentset
                            })
                        }
                    }]
                }

            }],
            columns: [ //my columns]
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Extjs uses MVC pattern, so you dont need to dig changed values manually. Your data records (clean and dirty ones) are in store, connection is managed by proxy. Grid is just a visual component to visualize the data and its plugins are helpers on changing the data.

Don't (re)create new request inside your function but tell the store to do the job:

```
handler: function () {
    form.updateRecord();
    form.hide();
    grid.getStore().sync();
}
```

also, specify proxy parameters:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    batchActions: true,
    url: './myownurl',
    actionMethods: {
        create: 'POST',
        read: 'POST',
        update: 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'results'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        encode: true,
        writeAllFields: true,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get the modified records using

```
grid.getStore().getModifiedRecords();
```

Gets all records added or updated since the last commit.